# Are spaces OK in set statements?

Tags: vimrc, options

Is it OK to use spaces for better readability in a .vimrc? For example, right now I have:

```
set number| "show line numbers
set history=1000
```

Would it be OK to write instead:

```
set number | "show line numbers
set history = 1000
```

I know that if a space is before the virgule in a key remapping then the space becomes part of the mapping, but in the example above the space would not seem to affect the `set`  operation.

Comment: You might want to [avoid end-of-line comments](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6922/205).

Comment: @muru why? putting comments on separate lines makes the config file a lot more spread out and confusing to read because some lines are code, others are comments

Comment: Because it might cause problems in map statements. And a personal preference of vertical spread over horizontal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`:help :set-args`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#:set-args):

> White space between {option} and '=' is allowed and
>   will be ignored.  White space between '=' and {value}
>   is not allowed.

So:

```
set history=1000 " is ok.
set history =1000 " is also ok, but
set history= 1000 " is not. Neighter is
set history = 1000
```

If the option doesn't take a value you can put as many spaces behind it as you want.

Comment: I have confirmed this behavior.