# Vertical split keymap suddenly broken

Tags: key-bindings, split

In my [vimrc](https://github.com/gfarrell/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc) I have a shortcut for opening a vertical split:

```
let mapleader = ','
map <leader>v :vsplit<CR> " ,v for vsplit
map <leader>s :split<CR>  " ,s for split
```

This has been working fine for months, but recently it's started misbehaving: almost every time I try to split the window, it does split but then changes a load of text at the cursor and leaves itself in *insert* mode.

Here's an example:

**before split**: `const queryValidation`
**after split**: `plit",                   n`

All that I did was hit `,v` which has been working fine until recently. I can't work out why this is happening now. My vim version is **7.4.2109**.

(This doesn't happen if I just use `:vsplit`)

Comment: `map <leader>s :split<CR>| " ,s for split`. Note the `|`.

Comment: By the way, `:vsplit` and `:split` already have normal mode commands: `<C-w>v` and `<C-w>s`. No need to waste keys on redundant shortcuts.

Comment: Note that [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6921/1841) had the same problem (btw the title doesn't indicate clearly that this is a duplicate) and [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/1841) I made also indicates how to solve this problem, it could be worth reading it for a further mapping problem :-)

Comment: @romainl yes, but `<C-w>v` is a lot more awkward for me to type than `,v`.

Comment: @statox that answer is killer, thanks. It could have been the eol-comments that did it.

Comment: It _was_ the eol-comments that did it.

Comment: Just to add to this: When you use `"` in a mapping, it will typically imply the normal mode key `"`, which indicates a register. For example, the following map will ensure that `dd` does not add to the most recent register, but instead save to the "black hole"-register: `nnoremap dd "_dd`. The point is, since `"` is a reasonable part of the right-hand side of a map, it can NOT be used to start a comment. This explains why the comments screw up your mapping, and why it works when you remove them.

Comment: @GTF: You can trust Karl he is right: the problem does come from the `"` comment. I'm not sure why it seemed to work before but Karl's explaination is totally right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use end-of-line comments, in particular for mappings. See `:h comment`. Also, I suggest that you use `nnoremap` instead of simply `map`. Thus, you should use:

```
nnoremap <leader>v :vsplit<CR>
nnoremap <leader>s :split<CR>
```

Comment: Could you explain why I should use `nnoremap` instead of `map` in this case? Thanks for the no eol comments, by the way, I think that *may* have done the trick (I'll give it a day or two to be sure, though).

Comment: I know it "did the trick". The eol comments screwed up your mapping. `nnoremap` ensures that the mapping is non recursive. If you do not need `map`, then you should always use `nnoremap` (or `noremap`). It is all well described in the docs, see `:h :map-commands`.